# Unusually slow query with MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, performance, express, mongoose

I used MongoDB with mongoose and express in my node.js app.

I query my database every day but sometimes (1 hour around ≈ 11 a.m), one of my query is very slow

It's a simple GET Request in short collection (Total documents 1097)

```
router.get('/cases', (req, res, next) => {
    Case.find()
        .select()
        .populate('created_by', 'username')
        .exec()
        .then(docs => {
            const response = {
                count: docs.length,
                cases: docs
            }
            res.status(200).json(response);
        })

        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).json({
                error: err
            });
        });
});
```

I think it's not my hosting because in local my request take 34s

I have the impression that it concerns all of my requests because even if they work, they remain long

Comment: What else is happening around 11 AM? Is some process e.g. grabbing a backup of the MongoDB server?

Comment: No, nothing different for example today it happened at 9am and it continues

Comment: System load also normal? Have you checked the MongoDB logs, and maybe https://medium.com/mongodb-cowboys/troubleshooting-mongodb-100-cpu-load-and-slow-queries-da622c6e1339 ?

Comment: I have checked https://medium.com/mongodb-cowboys/troubleshooting-mongodb-100-cpu-load-and-slow-queries-da622c6e1339 but its slow with all of my request even very very small request :/

Comment: Same problem today, I don't know what's going wrong